# How can I use first image in article as featured image?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, articles, extensions, images

I have searched all over the internet but nothing got useful. I have only hope on this forum. Please tell me how can I use the first image of the article in Joomla as featured image. I don't want to upload a featured image separately.

Comment: Have you found any tutorials or extension that get close to satisfying your requirements?  If so, please edit your question to include these links.  While you wait for support, please take the [tour].

Comment: Featured in relation to what?
Social media or...